# Vim commands on terminal do not work

Tags: applications, pantheon-terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

When using vim from within the terminal I have the following issues. Vim "visual selection" using Ctrl-v does not work. Instead the terminal tries to paste the last copied text.

When the vim window is split (using :sp) the bar that splits the vim windows is not adjustable.

Are these bugs? If not, is there anyway I can get xterm like behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use v and not Ctrl-v, or it will paste.

As for splits, it's working for me?

```
 Ctrl-w+  increase window size by 1 line
 Ctrl-w-  decrease window size by 1 line
 10 ctrl-w+  increase window size by 10 lines
 Ctrl-w=  make all equal size
```

Comment: Thank you. Ctrl-w+/- works but not moving with a mouse. Ctrl-v is visual copy in vim. v is plain copy. Ctrl-v doesn ot work

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to disable "natural copy paste" in Pantheon terminal

gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings natural-copy-paste false

That solves one problem.

Ctrl-W+ and W- only zooms in and out. Does not change window proportions

Answer (score 0):

For Elementary OS 5.x Juno, it has been set to a new location:

`gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings natural-copy-paste false`